# No cold water in shower, cartridge replacement didn't fix it

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge

A couple weeks ago we realized that there is no cold water in one of our showers.  When you turn the shower on, it is fully supplied with hot water.  When you turn the handle all the way to the cold side, the water turns off.

Overall cold water supply to the house is fine, including cold water to the other fixtures in the same bathroom, the other bathroom, and the kitchen.  So the problem seems to be localized to this specific shower.  This morning I tried replacing the cartridge as that seemed the most likely problem, but the same thing is happening with the new cartridge, suggesting that the problem is upstream.

This is an American Standard single-handle faucet.  The cartridge type is a 47mm 023529-0070A/H ([link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/American-Standard-Faucet-Replacement-47-MM-1-Handle-Trim-Valve-Cartridge-in-White-023529-0070A-H/203167607)).

At the store, I also saw a [pressure balancing unit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/American-Standard-Pressure-Balance-Unit-for-Single-Control-Tub-Shower-Valve-M952100-0070A/100423146) which seems to be a more internal component, and wondered if that could be the problem, but wanted to ask for advice before taking more things apart...

Thanks!

Comment: Does the valve body have internal stop valves? Is the cold one not open? Start simple...

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this problem with the culprit being either the pressure balance unit, ( usually incorporated into the cartridge)

Or a foreign body in the cold water line. ( found a screw lodged in the cold water inlet.)

Remove the cartridge and have someone turn the cold water on slowly to verify that you have water supplied to the cartridge.
If you do then the problem has to be in the cartridge/ balancer. The water out of the cartridge is mixed. ( if there is both cold and hot in.)